# Save frames to file onFrameAvailable [Google Project Tango]

Tags: java, android, google-project-tango

I am trying to save to files the RGB frames along with Pose data, and then do some post processing on them. The main issue is that currently the only way to do this using the Tango Java API is to render to a `GLSurfaceView`, by connecting them via

```
tangoCameraPreview.connectToTangoCamera(mTango,TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);
```

Then you would use `GlReadPixels` to read the pixels into an array and save that to a file.

The problem with this is that GlReadPixels is **slow**. In fact, using this I am getting about 3-4 fps using what I just described.

Looking at other, more general answers on taking a photo bursts, I have seen various people saying that when using `SurfaceView` instead of `GlSurfaceView`, they managed to get up to 15fps.

I didn't find any way to use `SurfaceView` with the tango camera, since `connectToTangoCamera` needs a `GlSurfaceView` and I can't just use `Camera` and bind that to a `SurfaceView` because when I'm trying to open it (via `Camera.open()`), it's already being used by `Tango`. `Tango` needs to use it in order to get the `colorToIMUPose` data.

So I'm really not sure what workaround might I find in order to be able to get at least 10fps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the C++ API with `TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable` where you will get a YUV frame buffer in a reasonable speed. Checkout the tango c example [video-overlay-jni-example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/video-overlay-jni-example) where they do the RGB conversion. I use this way to interface OpenCV filters to the rendering process.